Can Elastic Beanstalk be configured to always use the latest Launch Template version?
I'm experiencing a frustrating situation, and I hope someone can point me in the right direction.
I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk worker cluster. Under the hood, EB creates an Auto Scaling Group and a Launch Template.
When first setup, the Launch Template version is 1 and the Scaling Group is configured to use version 1.
But I needed to modify the Launch Template, which created a version 2. The Scaling Group was still configured to use version 1, so I changed it to use "Latest" (version). That worked fine.

But then a couple of days later I noticed that my modification was no longer working, and I found that now the most recent Launch Template did not include my change, and the Scaling Group was set to use a specific version, instead of "Latest".
Does anyone know what's going on here? Is EB creating new Launch Template versions itself, and not honoring my edit?
Thanks.
